# Expected value of tossing a coin thrice

Tags: probability, expected-value

A coin with probability 0.6 of coming up Heads is tossed three times. Let X be the number of Heads observed. Find E(X^2) (expected value of X^2)

I understand what I need to do but I'm a bit thrown off by the E(X^2) Does this mean the following is correct:

```
             E(X^2) = (1*6/10)^2 + (2*9/25)^2 + (3*27/125)^2 = 1.30
```

or is it:

```
             E(X^2) = ((1*6/10) + (2*9/25) + (3*27/125))^2 = 3.87
```

Comment: Putting it in words, it's asking for (the expected value of (the square of (the number of heads))). Which of what you put down is the same as that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm not sure where your specific numbers are coming from, but I'm getting that $P(0)=0.064$, $P(1)=0.288$, $P(2)=0.432$, and $P(3)=0.216$.)

So then using
$$
E[X^{2}] = \sum_{x} x^{2} P(x),
$$
we can see that
$$
\begin{aligned}
E[X^{2}] &= (0^{2})(0.064) + (1^{2})(0.288) + (2^{2})(0.432) + (3^{2})(0.216) \\
&= 0.288 + 1.728 + 1.944 \\
&= 3.96
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: How did you get those values for P(0), P(1).. ? It's a biased coin with 0.6 chance of being head so shouldn't it be P(1)=0.6, P(2)=0.6^2, P(3)=0.6^3 ?

Comment: When considering the probability of 1 head, you have to consider the three different ways it could happen (HTT, THT, TTH), and so you have 3 times (0.6*0.4*0.4). You may want to look up the Binomial distribution for some intuition on why what you describe doesn't make sense, but consider what your logic implies about zero heads: P(0)=0.6^0=1 ?